# Insert data in intermediate table created by spring

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using spring with JPA and I have 2 model classes

1. User
2. Resources

I have defined many to many relation using -

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "users_resources", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

This definition has created another table users_resources.

To insert data in users_resources table, the REST api is sending just the User id [primary key] and Resource Id [primary key].

Is there anyway I can insert data into users_resources without fetching full user object and resource object? I wanted to use native query but it seems PersistenceJPAConfig has noway to run native INSERT query.

Comment: Which class and field/method is anotated with above code?

Comment: "Spring" creates no tables, ever. JPA providers create tables

Comment: This is a very intriguing problem; I do not believe it can be solved without native queries or using a separate entity for the many-to-many table. Still, I would be very interested in a solution. Oh, and by the way, if either entity has a `@Version` field, you still need to update it to preserve its semantics, even with native queries!

Answer (score 2):

If you know Id of the object, and you need object reference (without object details) you could use `EntityManager.getReference()`

```
User userReference=em.getReference(User.class,userId);
Resource resourceReference=em.getReference(Resource.class,resourceId);
```

Using references will not exectue  any SELECTs from the database.

Comment: This will still read at least one entity + all the related ones when the collection is accessed to add the other entity, e.g. when you do `userReference.gerResources().add(resourceReference)` it will actually read the user and all its related resources to fill the collection.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos you are right. If you want to avoid selects, you need references to the excact thing you are using. You cannot call any get* method on your reference, because that will cause SELECT. 

If you cannot get that reference, then I see no way to avoid SELECT before INSERT.
Well, maybe native query - INSERT with nested select will do the trick.